# Security of Messaging between Content Script and Background Page in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am working on a Chrome Extension with a Content Script that sends a Message back to the Background page via chrome.runtime.sendMessage which triggers an action.

Does the Background page only accept Messages from my Content Script, or could it be hacked by a third party script that sends an identical Message in order to trigger the action?

Hope someone can help me, trying to get up to speed, and this is a security concern :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only your extension sees these messages.

In order to send the message to another extension you would have to [specify its ID explicitly](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external).

In order to receive the message from another extension you would have to declare `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal` or `chrome.runtime.onConnectExternal` listener and that other extension would have to specify the ID of yours explicitly.

The only case when another extension could hijack yours is when that another extension uses [chrome.debugger API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) but in that case Chrome displays a yellow warning on all pages. That warning may be disabled *manually* via `chrome://flags/#silent-debugger-extension-api` flag. Theoretically a sophisticated malicious native application may silently alter `Local State` file in Chrome data folder.

Comment: Aw, you beat me to it.

Comment: Also, regarding Secure Preferences - they are not called "secure" for nothing, as they are cryptographically signed.

Comment: Correction: it's `Local State` file above the user profile folder.